# acc-wizard for bootstrap disable the not clicked links

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

iam using the acc-wizard from here https://github.com/sathomas/acc-wizard. What i now want is that the links in the sidebar can only be clicked in the successfull class. ive searched for it but cant find it...here is an demostration of the acc-wizard http://sathomas.me/acc-wizard/#prerequisites. i have commented everything out where the js sets an href but its still there. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable all the links/steps in the sidebar using:

```
 $(".acc-wizard-todo").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

However, this would force the user to navigate through the wizard using the `Go Back`,`Next` buttons on the accordion panels.

Here is a working demo: http://bootply.com/63398

Comment: Thanks, the problem is, that i can now not click if the user has successfull filled in the data in the step. I want it that the user can only click and go back not go forward without clicking next. for eg.  User 1 filled in Step 1 and Step 2, and can click on those, but can not skipp step 3 if he clicks step 4!

Comment: okay, i changed it to: $(document).on('click', '.acc-wizard-todo', function(e) and then its working :)!